# Install Helm in specific version with brew

Tags: homebrew, kubernetes-helm

I tried:

```
~ ❯ brew install helm@3.4.2                                                                                                        at 11:05:02
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "helm@3.4.2".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Also tried to install from a specific commit hash as several guides online suggested but got this error:

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:227:in `load_file': Invalid usage: Installation of helm from a GitHub commit URL is unsupported! 'brew extract helm' to stable tap on GitHub instead. (UsageError)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$ brew search` to list all available formulas:

```sh
$ brew search helm
helm  helm@2  helmfile  helmsman
```

You can install one of the versions from the shown result:

```sh
$ brew install helm
or 
$ brew install helm@2
```

From [Helm](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/):

> Members of the Helm community have contributed a Helm formula build to Homebrew. This formula is generally up to date.

Comment: So there is no way to install other version than latest with brew

Comment: @deez it seems like!

Comment: But you can download your desire version from the [binary release](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases).